# summarise to sum cells containing multiple strings

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to use str_detect with sum to add variables containing sets of strings. How to use **AND** below to detect variables containing **all** strings irrespective of order?

"|" works in this instance but not "&"

reproducible example:

```
data<- data.frame("order" = c("A","B","C","A:B","A:B:C","B:C"))

wrong.out <- data %>% summarise("total"=n(),
                           "A"= sum(str_detect(order, "A"), na.rm = TRUE),
                           "B"= sum(str_detect(order, "B"), na.rm = TRUE),
                           "C"= sum(str_detect(order, "C"), na.rm = TRUE),
                           "A:B"= sum(str_detect(order, "(A)&(B)"), na.rm = TRUE),
                           "A:B:C"= sum(str_detect(order, "(A)&(B)&(C)"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

I am looking for totals as below that count any cell containing both A&B, or A&B&C:

```
expected.out <- data.frame("total" = "6",
                      "A"="3",
                       "B"="4",
                       "C"="3",
                       "A:B"="2", 
                         "A:B:C"="1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_detect` separately for `&` condition.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

summarise("Total" = n(),
          "CD8:PD-1" = sum(str_detect(ordered, "PD-1") & 
                           str_detect(ordered, "CD8"),na.rm = TRUE),
          "CD8:PD:1:FoxP3" = sum(str_detect(ordered, "PD-1") & 
                                 str_detect(ordered, "CD8") &
                                 str_detect(ordered, "FoxP3"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
data %>% summarise("total"=n(),
                                "A"= sum(str_detect(order, "A"), na.rm = TRUE),
                                "B"= sum(str_detect(order, "B"), na.rm = TRUE),
                                "C"= sum(str_detect(order, "C"), na.rm = TRUE),
                                "A:B"= sum(str_detect(order, "A:B"), na.rm = TRUE),
                                "A:B:C"= sum(str_detect(order, "A:B:C"), na.rm = TRUE))

  total A B C A:B A:B:C
1     6 3 4 3   2     1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a solution to sum when the strings are present in any order. ie A:B:C would be still counted when strings are in the order B:C:A